# What was the issue the UAE had with RIM/Blackberry and what was the outcome? What countries have similar agreements?

Tags: mobile, government

I'd like to understand what came out of UAE's desire to monitor RIM traffic, and what technical compromise was made.

Do other countries have similar agreements with RIM?  What are the details?  Please post references, or any supplemental information to the best of your knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I interpret the news there was no technical solution made. RIM made a contract with the UAE as well as India that they hand over communication of specific customers. It is not public under what circumstances they'll do it. There is only speculation around.

- [India has lawful access](http://content.usatoday.com/communities/ondeadline/post/2010/08/after-blackberry-india-now-wants-access-to-google-skype-vpn-data-/1), [BlackBerry assures India on access to services](http://www.reuters.com/article/idUSTRE67151F20100813)
- [Turkey wants RIM data](http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/n.php?n=blackberry-maker-refuses-to-compromise-on-encryption-2010-10-26)

So the three known countries are UAE, India and Turkey. Maybe others want it too. If you google around you'll find more details.