# Can BlackBerry keep us safe from network providers

Tags: web-browser, mobile

I recently brought a BlackBerry mobile and the reason I have gone with BB was the security it ensures and now I have a doubt.

That said in the Internet, Massage from BBM will first reach Canada via our network provider carrier:

- Is there any possibility that our N/W provider can spoof our data in the middle before it reaches RIM?
- Can BlackBerry keep us safe when we are surfing in the Internet for Facebook and so?
- Recently I have also heard that our network providers are monitoring our activities in the Internet if so how can common men and women keep privacy of their own?

Answer (score 2):

It does depend on what protocols you're using to access the network provider.

The legacy network is still operational but was once [audited by the UAE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/576/396), and had some [interesting security properties.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/9929/396)

Now you are probably using a modern BES device.  Most of this relies on standard TLS protocols, which is arguably more secure depending on the version you're using.

For example, modern Activesync devices use TLS, whereas prior users had to proxy through a private VPN of sorts maintained by BES and their patented network.  As long as you [trust your root certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2268/396), you should be OK.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing can keep you 100% safe on the Internet, I have never owned a BlackBerry, so you'll have to wait for another user to help you with the first question.

**Can BlackBerry keep us safe when we are surfing in the Internet for Facebook and so?**

No. Although this does depend on where you are in the world, such as if you're in the US, everything has backdoors in it. This also depends if you are connected through 3G/4G or WiFi. Although the encryption used in phone messaging is getting better, so are the crypto-analysts at the NSA, FBI or whoever...

**How can common men and women keep privacy of their own?**

With phones, I'm not sure you can do much apart from installing a VPN client...

However in general, I suggest you familiarize yourself with Tor (The Onion Router). Here are the basic security measures you can take with the Tor browser:

LEVEL 1: Tor Browser installed, running on Windows... (*Sigh*) = You are still monitored and are most definitely on a watchlist.

LEVEL 2: Tor Browser installed, running on Linux. (*Yay!*) = Linux doesn't constantly log your personal information, this is the level of security most people will take.

LEVEL 3: Tor Browser installed, running on Tails Linux distro (*Uber-Ninja Mode*) = Basically the height of security. Tails was built to work with Tor, so almost everything is encrypted and safe. If you really want to be sure, get a USB stick, and cram Tails on it!

[Tor Browser homepage](https://www.torproject.org/)

[Tails homepage](https://tails.boum.org/)

Comment: Very opinion-based answer. If you followed the leaks you would also know that especially Tails and Tor are being monitored, so technically you are drawing a giant target on yourself. Also TOR is somehow still often suggested against surveillance though it is one of the most targeted services with some successful attempts to de-anonymize Users.

Comment: Also it does not answer OPs question regarding features and security of BlackBerry which certainly does not run windows and you can't run Tails on it as far as I am aware.